# Derivative of a constant tensor field along a path

Tags: tensor-calculus

I understand that the time derivative of a tensor filed $\mathbf T$ along a curve $\gamma\left(t\right)$ can be shown to be,
$$  \frac { d\mathbf{T}}{ dt } = \left(\frac { dT^{ i } }{ dt }  + V^{ k }\Gamma ^{ i }_{ km }T^{ m }\right)\mathbf e_i = T^i\mathbf e_i$$

where,
$\mathbf e_i$ is the covarient basis and $V^k$ is the velocity component of the position vector w.r.t covarient basis ($\mathbf V = V^k\mathbf e_k$).$$$$
My question is how to prove that $\frac{d\mathbf T}{dt}$ becomes zero when the tensor field $\mathbf T$ along the curve $\gamma\left(t\right)$ is constant? Any hint on this will also be very important.

Comment: What is the meaning of "constant" for you?

Comment: Assume Euclidian space with general (non-affine) coordinate system, and then I think constant tensor field should be clear. For example parallel and constant magnitude vector field.

Comment: The point is that check if a tensor field is constant, you have to compare tensors applied at different points of the space. In an Euclidean or in an affine space, there is a canonical way to identify these tensor spaces localized at different points, using the fact that translations act transitively and freely. As a matter of fact, a tensor field is constant if its components are constant in Cartesian coordinates (nomatter the choice of the Cartesian frame). In the absence of an affine structure, the notion of constant field is ambiguous, even if all the points belongs to  a given curve.

Comment: In that case you have to select a preferred way to transport tensors along the curve. This is done by the notion of parallel transport defined respect to an affine connection (the Levi-Civita one, for instance, if the manifold is equipped with a (pseudo)Riemannian metric). By **definition** a tensor field is *constant  along a give curve*  if it is parallely transported along the curve.  So there is nothing to prove, just a definition.

Comment: Sorry for the typos in my comments, I am in a hurry...